# flask does not handle uriencoded parameters the same way on appengine and dev_appserver

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, urlencode

I've been struggling with this for a while, and can't seem to figure it out.
I have a google appengine project, with flask, and I need a route that handles base64 URIencoded data.

Here is the handler I have for this route:

```
@app.route('/test/<data1>/<data2>', methods=['GET'])
def test(data1, data2):
    return "data1:%s<br>data2:%s"%(data1, data2)
```

Now, this works nicely when running with dev_appserver:

```
http://localhost/test/hi/there
# returns:
data1:hello
data2:there
```

and

```
http://localhost/test/hi%2fho/there
# returns:
data1:hi%2Fho
data2:there
```

which is what I would expect.

Using the same urls on a deployed version to appengine:

- The first one returns the same result
- The second one fails, because the `%2f` gets decoded before the routing to a `/`, therefore the route does not match the pattern anymore.

My question(s):

- Why does appengine (or flask?) decode the url **before** routing ?
- Why is the behavior not consistent between local and deployed appengine ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Looks like a bug.  I suggest reporting here: https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559750

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've created a bug report [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79311040). Any idea how long it would take them to give me an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79311040) on google's issue tracker, and someone acknowledged it.

I guess we just have to wait now.